# In memory representation of large data

Tags: c#

Currently, I am working on a project where I need to bring GBs of data on to client machine to do some task and the task needs whole data as it do some analysis on the data and helps in decision making process.

so the question is, what are the best practices and suitable approach to manage that much amount of data into memory without hampering the performance of client machine and application.

note: at the time of application loading, we can spend time to bring data from database to client machine, that's totally acceptable in our case. but once the data is loaded into application at start up, performance is very important.

Comment: And your problem is? Regular machines easly support 16/32GB of physical RAM and provide pretty much unlimited address space for .Net processes on x64 editions of Windows... so what part of data managment you have problem with?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov having that much space doesn't mean that *using* it is free...

Comment: @MarcGravell, sure... but the only requiremt OP provided is "performance is very important" - making sure all data fits in physical memory and preferably immutable may be cheapes approach if amount of data is small (i.e. 10GB).

Answer (score 15):

This is a little hard to answer without a problem statement, i.e. what problems you are currently facing, but the following is just *some thoughts*, based on some recent experiences we had in a similar scenario. It is, however, a lot of work to change to this type of model - so it also depends how much you can invest trying to "fix" it, and I can make no promise that "your problems" are the same as "our problems", if you see what I mean. So don't get cross if the following approach doesn't work for you!

---

Loading that much data into memory is always going to have some impact, however, I think I see what you are doing...

When loading that much data naively, you are going to have many (millions?) of objects and a similar-or-greater number of references. You're obviously going to want to be using x64, so the references will add up - but in terms of *performance* the biggesst problem is going to be garbage collection. You have a lot of objects that **can never be collected**, but the GC is going to know that you're using a ton of memory, and is going to try *anyway* periodically. This is something I looked at [in more detail here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/assault-by-gc.html), but the following graph shows the impact - in particular, those "spikes" are all GC killing performance:

[image: http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/assault-by-gc.html]

For this scenario (a huge amount of data loaded, never released), we switched to *using structs*, i.e. loading the data into:

```
struct Foo {
    private readonly int id;
    private readonly double value;
    public Foo(int id, double value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int Id {get{return id;}}
    public double Value {get{return value;}}
}
```

and stored those directly *in arrays* (not lists):

```
Foo[] foos = ...
```

the significance of that is that because some of these structs are quite big, we didn't want them copying themselves lots of times on the stack, but with an array you can do:

```
private void SomeMethod(ref Foo foo) {
     if(foo.Value == ...) {blah blah blah}
}
// call ^^^
int index = 17;
SomeMethod(ref foos[index]);
```

Note that we've passed the object *directly* - it was never copied; `foo.Value` is actually looking directly *inside* the array. The tricky bit starts when you need relationships between objects. You can't store a *reference* here, as it is a `struct`, and you can't *store* that. What you *can* do, though, is store the *index* (into the array). For example:

```
struct Customer {
      ... more not shown
      public int FooIndex { get { return fooIndex; } }
}
```

Not quite as convenient as `customer.Foo`, but the following works nicely:

```
Foo foo = foos[customer.FooIndex];
// or, when passing to a method, SomeMethod(ref foos[customer.FooIndex]);
```

Key points:

- we're now using half the size for "references" (an `int` is 4 bytes; a reference on x64 is 8 bytes)
- we don't have several-million object headers in memory
- we don't have a huge object graph for GC to look at; only a small number of arrays that GC can look at *incredibly* quickly
- but it is a little less convenient to work with, and needs some initial processing when loading

additional notes:

- strings are a killer; if you have millions of strings, then that is problematic; at a minimum, if you have strings that are repeated, make sure you do some custom interning (not `string.Intern`, that would be bad) to ensure you only have one instance of each repeated value, rather than 800,000 strings with the same contents
- if you have repeated data of finite length, rather than sub-lists/arrays, you might consider a `fixed` array; this requires `unsafe` code, but avoids another myriad of objects and references

---

As an additional footnote, with that volume of data, you should think very seriously about your serialization protocols, i.e. how you're sending the data down the wire. I would strongly suggest staying far away from things like `XmlSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer` or `BinaryFormatter`. If you want pointers on this subject, let me know.

Comment: I'd probably build a database (sql compact maybe, or access MDB), copy that over, then LINQ2SQL my way through it on the client machine... But this answer of yours makes me wonder if it would be a decent approach.

Comment: +1. As usual incredible answer for not necessary the most clear question :)